# Rdlc SubReport issue, Cant use the List(of Object) Property from objectdatasource in report or subreport

Tags: vb.net, rdlc

I am trying to create an RDLC report in VB.net 2008 using object datasource.

The thing is, my object datasource is a list of `Item` objects.
Each `Item` object has a property named `Stock` - which is a list of `ItemStock` objects.
The main properties of both classes are as follows:

```
Item Class:
Name,Id, Stock,<and some other like MRP,Tax etc.>

ItemStock Class:
BranchId,BatchNo,Expirydate,StockQuantity
```

A single `Item` object can contain a number of `ItemStock` items for each `BranchId`. The `Item.Stock` property will be therefore the union of such stock items, i.e. `List( of ItemStock)`.

Now, my report named Stock report will have a `List(of Item)` object as a datasource(binding source). I get the required object list with no error at all.
I assign the list to a Datagrid to display branchwise aggregate stock values.
That is:

```
Itemname         Branch1    Branch2   Branch2
item1               12         2         3
```

This works fine, as I have used LINQ to get the sum of stock values for item in each branch, by handling the `Cell_format` event

But the problem arises when I create a report. My report needs to be in format:

```
Item1 Name
     Branch     BatchNo   Expiry      Quantity
     Branch1    12677     12/09/2009    56 
     Branch1    1217      04/04/2010    6 
     Branch2    22644     12/03/2011    16 
     Branch3    72600     12/02/2012    7 

Item2 Name
     Branch     BatchNo   Expiry       Quantity
     Branch1    2677     12/09/2009      5 
     Branch2    244      12/03/2011      1 
     Branch3    7200     12/02/2012      7
```

Now I can't understand how to use the property `Stock` on an `Item` object to display this report.
I have an option of using a subreport, which I created. But I can not figure out how to assign the stock property of particular item object while processing the subreport.

I also tried handling `SubreportProcessing` event as follows:

```
  Private Sub SubreportProcessing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SubreportProcessingEventArgs)
        e.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("Chemasis_BusinessObjects_Objects_ItemStock", ctype(itemBindingSource.Current,Item).Stock))
    End Sub
```

But obviously, this takes the first item in `ItemBindingSource` and so, all the stock values are displayed as the same.